# Search Using ComboBox and TextBox

Tags: mysql, vb.net, combobox

i have a mini assignment in vb that will search student record

the search textbox is use to record and the selected a column on the combo box,

[image]

```
Private Sub search()
    'search method for Search Record'
    Try
        If cmbKeywords.Text = "ID" Then
            Dim dbQuery As String = "Select * from tblstudents where id =" & txtSearch.Text
        ElseIf cmbKeywords.Text = "Name" Then
            Dim dbQuery As String = "Select * from tblstudents where id =" & txtSearch.Text
        ElseIf cmbKeywords.Text = "Address" Then
            Dim dbQuery As String = "Select * from tblstudents where id =" & txtSearch.Text
        ElseIf cmbKeywords.Text = "Contact" Then
            Dim dbQuery As String = "Select * from tblstudents where id =" & txtSearch.Text
        ElseIf cmbKeywords.Text = "Civil Status" Then
            Dim dbQuery As String = "Select * from tblstudents where id =" & txtSearch.Text
        End If
        Dim dbConnection As New MySqlConnection(dbConString)
        Dim dbCmd As New MySqlCommand(dbQuery, dbConnection)
        Dim dbReader As MySqlDataReader
        dbConnection.Open()
        dbReader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader()

        dgvRecords.ReadOnly = True

        dgvRecords.ColumnCount = 6
        dgvRecords.Columns(0).Name = "Stud ID"
        dgvRecords.Columns(1).Name = "Name"
        dgvRecords.Columns(2).Name = "Address"
        dgvRecords.Columns(3).Name = "Gender"
        dgvRecords.Columns(4).Name = "Status"
        dgvRecords.Columns(5).Name = "Contact No"

        While dbReader.Read()
            dgvRecords.Rows.Add(dbReader("id"), dbReader("lastname") & ", " & dbReader("firstname") & " " & dbReader("middlename"), dbReader("address"), dbReader("gender"), dbReader("civil_status"), dbReader("contact"))
        End While
        dbReader.Close()
        dbConnection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("ERROR: " & ErrorToString(), MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
End Sub
```

i have a error on this line.

```
Dim dbCmd As New MySqlCommand(dbQuery, dbConnection)
```

it says dbQuery is no define.
can someone help me in this?
sorry newbie in vb here.

Comment: Define `dbQuery` above Try Block. And use it later as variable in iF block.

Comment: @Mahadev, there's no reason to declare the variable outside the `Try` block because it's not used outside that block.  Outside the `If` block is all that's required.

Comment: @jmcilhinney : Yep. My Bad. Thanks for notifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's due to scope of your `dbQuery` variable. As you are declaring it inside `If- ElseIf-End If` it is local variable to this condition, outside the condition it doesn't exists. You have to make it local for whole function so you can refer it through out the function. Below is the better answer.
Try this

```
Private Sub search()
'search method for Search Record'
Dim dbQuery As String
Try
    If cmbKeywords.Text = "ID" Then
        dbQuery = "Select * from tblstudents where id =" & txtSearch.Text
    ElseIf cmbKeywords.Text = "Name" Then
        dbQuery = "Select * from tblstudents where id =" & txtSearch.Text
    ElseIf cmbKeywords.Text = "Address" Then
        dbQuery = "Select * from tblstudents where id =" & txtSearch.Text
    ElseIf cmbKeywords.Text = "Contact" Then
        dbQuery = "Select * from tblstudents where id =" & txtSearch.Text
    ElseIf cmbKeywords.Text = "Civil Status" Then
        dbQuery = "Select * from tblstudents where id =" & txtSearch.Text
    End If
    Dim dbConnection As New MySqlConnection(dbConString)
    Dim dbCmd As New MySqlCommand(dbQuery, dbConnection)
    Dim dbReader As MySqlDataReader
    dbConnection.Open()
    dbReader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader()

    dgvRecords.ReadOnly = True

    dgvRecords.ColumnCount = 6
    dgvRecords.Columns(0).Name = "Stud ID"
    dgvRecords.Columns(1).Name = "Name"
    dgvRecords.Columns(2).Name = "Address"
    dgvRecords.Columns(3).Name = "Gender"
    dgvRecords.Columns(4).Name = "Status"
    dgvRecords.Columns(5).Name = "Contact No"

    While dbReader.Read()
        dgvRecords.Rows.Add(dbReader("id"), dbReader("lastname") & ", " & dbReader("firstname") & " " & dbReader("middlename"), dbReader("address"), dbReader("gender"), dbReader("civil_status"), dbReader("contact"))
    End While
    dbReader.Close()
    dbConnection.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("ERROR: " & ErrorToString(), MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem of scope.  If you declare `dbQuery` inside an `If` or `ElseIf` block then it only exists inside that block.  All those declarations actually create separate variables that cease to exist at the `End If` statement.

The solution is to declare the `dbQuery` variable once only, BEFORE the `If` statement, and then just assign to it in those multiple places.  Because the variable is declared at a wider scope, it is accessible after the `If Else` line.